# When select option selected show another select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do something for my web page. Basicly what I want, is when a user selects an option from select menu or even better, when option from option group selected, based on what option he selected, another select menu will appear. Or even better if somebody know here, is it possible to have select menu behave like a multiple level drop down menu(When hover on one item, side menu appears so there wouldn't have to be showing another select menu)?
Here is my code:

```js
$("#select1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 3) {
    $("#select2").show();
  } else {
    $("#select2").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1" name="optgroups">
  <optgroup label="group1">
    <option value="2">1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="group2">
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="group3">
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<select id="select2" style="display:none;">
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

Thanks a lot to whoever figures this out!

Comment: Your code seems to work as written. What's the problem?

Comment: If you're wanting things like nested dropdowns or menus, I'd strongly recommend something like bootstrap.  Stuff like that becomes very easy.  http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: You can't do multilevel menus with `<select>` but you can do it with CSS menus, and maybe the `Select2` plugin can do it easily for you.

Comment: Why not do it just like that: http://jsfiddle.net/jjow32uq/2/

Comment: I am using bootstrap @CrazyPaste

Comment: @Barmar It seems to be working here, but it is not working in my file. I am getting really frustrated

Comment: Select menus are native a cannot have mouseover events.

Comment: @DimitrijeMitic There's no way for us to know what you're doing differently in the real file. Maybe you have duplicate IDs? Maybe you didn't put the event binding in `$(document).ready()`?